# Use windows container или use linux container в Docker Desktop for Windows?

Tags: docker, windows-10

При установке [Docker Desktop for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/) инсталлятор спрашивает, какой режим использовать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чём между ними разница и какой вариант более стабильно работает на современных windows 10? (Я слышал, что раньше докер под windows это была конкретная боль и кактусы, эта галка как-то повлияет на глючность/безглючность)

Если несложно -- можно из своего опыта порекомендовать, а не капитанствовать "видишь галка по умолчанию не проставлена -- так и оставь".

Answer (score 1):

Это опция, которая переключается на лету, через иконку в трее.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Там есть два (три) режима:

- Linux - Docker поднимает виртуалку с Moby Linux, хостит в ней контейнеры, порты и файлы. [В этом режиме можно поднимать только linux-контейнеры](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/linux-containers#linux-containers-in-a-moby-vm).
- Windows - Docker хостит windows-контейнеры как process-isolated. В этом режиме можно поднимать только windows-контейнеры. Учитывая размер и время старта базовых образов под windows - его есть смысл использовать только для упаковки не-core приложений в докер.
- [Windows + LCOW](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/linux-containers#linux-containers-with-hyper-v-isolation) - доступен при включении Experimental Features в свойствах Docker. В этом режиме можно одновременно поднимать и Windows и Linux контейнеры. Windows изолируются через process isolation, linux - через hyper-v isolation. Стабильность linux-контейнеров при этом так себе, есть ограничения с поддержкой фич, да еще и платформу надо для каждого контейнера явно указывать - намучаетесь со стандартными примерами.

Если не хотите приключений, и хотите просто проразрабатывать под Docker - берите Linux-режим, на него сейчас ориентирован весь tooling, включая поддержку Docker в Visual Studio.